# How to set a default value to ng-options (multiple select)

Tags: angularjs

I wanted to set a default value to my ng-options by using `ng-init`, `ng-model`, etc. They didn't work at all. My code is following:

**Angular**

```
var app = angular.module('role', []);

app.controller('fooController', function($scope){
    $scope.roles = [{id:1, name:"Administrator"}, {id:2, name: "Student"}];
    $scope.user.roles = $scope.roles[0];
});
```

**HTML**

```
<body data-ng-app="role" data-ng-controller="fooController">
  <select multiple class="form-control" data-ng-model="user.roles" data-ng-options="role.name for role in roles" required=""></select>
</body>
```

Here is my [Plunkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/WIo3UgoZ0vIJy4OrXC57?p=preview)
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> **Update:**
>
> If you want to get directly to the reference used in this answer, here it is:
>
> Reference:
> [**Initial Selection In AngularJS ng-options with track by**](http://gurustop.net/blog/2014/01/28/common-problems-and-solutions-when-using-select-elements-with-angular-js-ng-options-initial-selection/)

Here's what worked for me:

```
app.controller('fooController', function($scope){
    $scope.roles = [{id:1, name:"Administrator"}, {id:2, name: "Student"}];
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.user.roles = [ $scope.roles[0] ];
});
```

There was an error in the plunk that `user` wasn't initialized, apart from this, Angular would compare every object in the `ng-options` array to every element in the `ng-model` array. JavaScript comparison not Angular comparison, comparing 2 objects even with same properties in JavaScript returns false (different objects).

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/ccsAVvPACnN6Qzje7HcB?p=preview

.

Now, this is not ideal. Typically you want to correlate these based on ID or so, here's another way:

In HTML, use `track by` to tell AngularJS to compare IDs instead of entire objects:

```
  <select multiple class="form-control" 
    data-ng-model="user.roles" 
    data-ng-options="role.name for role in roles track by role.id" 
    required=""></select>
```

Then in your controller, you can use any object without actually being in the array:

```
app.controller('fooController', function($scope){
    $scope.roles = [{id:1, name:"Administrator"}, {id:2, name: "Student"}];
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.user.roles = [ {id:1, name:"Administrator"} ];
});
```

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/NKLXrwqwk36YfhBSXILN?p=preview

Note that I didn't even need the `name` property. It's just for making a proper object later, but it really isn't needed for matching now, try without it!

.

I wrote a detailed tutorial with an accompanying video on this initial selection problem and its variations. It's focused on single-select but multi-select is just using an array of objects instead of one object directly.

Check it out for more understanding -- highly recommended:

[**Initial Selection In AngularJS ng-options with track by**](http://gurustop.net/blog/2014/01/28/common-problems-and-solutions-when-using-select-elements-with-angular-js-ng-options-initial-selection/)

.

Let me know in comments if you are still struggling with this.

Comment: Really clear explanation! Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Always glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

if your model is like `$scope.user.roles = [1];` then your `ng-options` should be like this,

```
  data-ng-options="role.id as role.name for role in roles"
```

this will select only the `ID`

if you do like `data-ng-options="role.name for role in roles"` then your model should be like

```
$scope.user.roles = [{id:1, name:"Administrator"}];
```

because this will select the whole object

and in your controller

```
$scope.user = {}; //this line should be add
```

because your trying to access a `roles` property of `user` but there is no `user` object defined, this will also occur a error

here is the [Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wuXelW2l9sh1WRUgAk9o?p=preview)

---

here is the updated [plunker1](http://plnkr.co/edit/wuXelW2l9sh1WRUgAk9o?p=preview) [plunker2](http://plnkr.co/edit/wuXelW2l9sh1WRUgAk9o?p=preview) for your case of `ng-options`

you can use `ng-init` here. please check.

Comment: Thanks for your response. when I tried your second approach, it didn't work as expected. Please see this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xwYtRjilBqr2pK3NlHUd?p=preview).

Comment: yes it's select the value, you can sure about it because you can see the selected values in `{{ user.roles }}` ,  but it doesn't show on the select box. don't know why :(

Comment: Actually, I have been trying to find a solution for two hours by using the same approach as your second approach but still can't figure it out. :(. BTW +1 for your help. Please let me know if you can figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
<body ng-init="role.name = roles[0].name" data-ng-app="role" data-ng-controller="fooController">
  <select multiple class="form-control" data-ng-model="user.roles" data-ng-options="role.name for role in roles" required=""></select>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Plunkr has errors. You have to define `$scope.user = {};` before you use it. Then it will work.

Note: This will only set an initial value to model. If you want to make Administrator highlighted by default, you'll have to figure out some other way.