# Angular Drop Down When NgModel is an Object

Tags: angularjs

I have a server that requires a JSON like such `{id1: '1', name: 'one' }`. The server also brings me back my data in this notation.
The problem is when I have a multiple select drop down that allows the user to select multiple items.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope, thingService) {
    //thing service is the service that returns objects likc such {id: 1, name: 'one'}

    $scope.data = [
        {id: 1, name: 'one'},
        {id: 2, name: 'two'},
        {id: 3, name: 'three'}
    ];

    $scope.selectedItems = thingService.getMyItems(); //this returns [{ id: 2, name: 'two' }]
    // alternatively we can have $scope.selectedItem = [{ id: 2, name: 'two' }]

    $scope.saveselection = function() {
        // performs a save operation to the service.
        // not really important for this demo.
    }

});
```

markup:

```
<select multiple
        ng-options='item.id as item.name for item in data'
        ng-model='selectedItems'>
</select>
```

Because objects are data bound by reference rather than by value. It seems like I will need additional code that will map the object returned by `thingService` to the `data` collection or else my drop down on load will never select the items that come from `thingService`.

What would be the best way to solve this issue? And can I avoid a quadratic loop (one that goes through selectedItems and one that goes through data to get this mapping?)

Comment: You can use `track by item.id` in `ng-options` here and the objects would then be compared using the `id` property. The model would be saved with ids only then though so you'll need to expand then before saving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<select multiple ng-options='item.name for item in data track by item.id' 
 ng-model='selectedItem'></select>
```

You need to add track by `item.id` to tell AngularJS to compare IDs instead of entire objects: Refer This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351251/how-to-set-a-default-value-to-ng-options-multiple-select)

[Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RvkWqbkLVOw1ejlkqnnr?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by Sergiu Paraschiv, you can use the `track by` and, if I you need to get items, you can edit the ng-options like this: `[...] ng-options='item as item.name for item [...]`

Bye