# Angular pre-select multiple values in Multi Select field

Tags: angularjs

Trying to pre-select multiple values in my selectfield.

My HTML

```
    <select multiple 
            data-ng-options="e.id for e in myElements"
            data-ng-model="mySelect">
    </select>
```

Put data in the select box (works fine)

```
    var elements = [
        { "id": "AAA" },
        { "id": "BBB" },
        { "id": "CCC" },
        { "id": "DDD" },
        { "id": "EEE" },
        { "id": "FFF" },
        { "id": "GGG" }
    ]
    $scope.myElements = elements;
```

This does NOT work

```
    var preselected = [
        { "id": "BBB" },
        { "id": "DDD" },
        { "id": "FFF" }
    ]
    $scope.mySelect = preselected;
```

This does NOT work

```
    var preselected = [ "BBB", "DDD", "FFF" ]
    $scope.mySelect = preselected;
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a default value to ng-options (multiple select)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351251/how-to-set-a-default-value-to-ng-options-multiple-select)

Comment: I read something about `track by elements.id` but im not quite sure how that would work?

Comment: The accepted answer to the linked question explains how. There are live examples of different approaches. I just messed with one and it works in the latest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1- **Use `as` and `track by` if you want objects as selected values** ([PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/UermV15ec3q8GosuIWHP?p=preview))

```
ng-options="e as e.id for e in vm.elements track by e.id"
```

*HTML*

```
<select multiple
    ng-options="e as e.id for e in vm.elements track by e.id"
    ng-model="vm.selecetedValues">
</select>
```

*CONTROLLER*

```
function MainCtrl() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.elements  = [{ "id": "AAA" },{ "id": "BBB" },{ "id": "CCC" }];

    vm.selectedValues = [
        { "id": "AAA" },
        { "id": "CCC" }
    ];
}
```

---

2- **Only Use `as` syntax if you want strings or numbers as selected values** ([PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/kBsewINJsS07Py88TRwK?p=preview))

```
ng-options="e.id as e.name for e in elements"
```

- *first argument `e.id` is the value of selected option*
- *second argument `e.name` is the displayed value*

In your case: `ng-options="e.id as e.id for e in elements"`

*HTML*

```
<select multiple
    ng-options="e.id as e.id for e in vm.elements"
    ng-model="vm.selecetedValues">
</select>
```

*CONTROLLER*

```
function MainCtrl() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.elements  = [{ "id": "AAA" },{ "id": "BBB" },{ "id": "CCC" }];

    vm.selectedValues= [
        "BBB",
        "DDD"
    ];
}
```

Comment: Bear - that worked! Both of them!!  I didnt know the trick where you use the vm.elements and vm.selectedValues.  Thanks for teaching me something new :)

Comment: I've used `controller as` syntax. Check this [John Papa guideline](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controlleras-view-syntax) to know more about it. Also, check  these posts (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287794/angularjs-controller-as-syntax-clarification) and (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers)

Comment: Hmm I said that too early.  How do you define vm?  `var vm = this;` ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry, I forgot that line in the answer (I've edited). That line is just to not write `this` lot of times.

Comment: Hmm do I also need to define vm as the controller? `<div id="wrapper" ng-controller="myForm as vm" ` ?

Comment: Yes - that did the trick. Now I am getting data in the select fields. but the `ng-model="vm.selecetedValues"`is not working.

Comment: Ahh you made a typo `selecetedValues`should be ´selectedValues`- didnt see that one at first hehe :-D

Comment: Perfect. It was weird if it doesn't work because you were doing well...  Good Luck :)

Comment: Bear - one last thing.  Say I want to put a custom option as the first element `<option label="ALL" value="ALL">ALL ELEMENTS</option>` - how would I do that?  Is there a way to insert that into the elements after they get their data from mongodb (thats what they do now).

Comment: I tried to do this, but it does not work `vm.propertyIdList = [{ "_id": "ALL" }] + response.data.data;` any suggestions would be very welcome :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144405/discussion-between-the-bear-and-torbenrudgaard).